# Processes Files Using Subprocess and Os

Tags: python, performance

This program I have written automates some of the more manual work in getting the results from my experiments.

The idea is that I have folders and subdirectories in my main directory. Some of these subdirectories contain the data I need process. Inside each of these subdirectories that contain data, there are another five subdirectories with the files. To process these files, I must run a program called **processResults.py**.

For example, if I have two data folders, then each of these will have 5 subdirectories for a total of 10 subdirectories, each of which must have **processResults.py** copied into and then ran.

Running **processResults.py** produces a new directory called **results** that has a summary csv file inside it called **Summary_Total.csv**.

All **Summary_Total.csv** files in a given data folder must be concatenated into a new csv file for processing. So, in our example, there would be two end product csv's that each contain 5 Summary_Total csvs, one for each original subdirectory.

The process described above is what I have automated through a program called **generate_results.py**.

Before I provide a manual demonstration and an automated one, I want to say that I am looking to

**1. Reduce the number of lines of my code**

**2. Make the code more efficient or optimized**

**3. Improve documentation**

After the demonstrations, the code for **processResults.py** and **generate_results.py**, the program I would like to improve, is provided.

```
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ ls
N_Test          UN_Test         processResults.py      generate_results.py
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd N_Test
(base) ip-75-193:N_Test trevormartin$ cat
x_1         x_3         x_5
x_2         x_4
(base) ip-75-193:N_Test trevormartin$ cd ..; cd UN_Test; ls; cd ..
xx_1        xx_3        xx_5
xx_2        xx_4
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$
```

**The subdirectories x_1 ... x_5 and xx_1 ... xx_5 are currently empty**

For testing here is what you should do:

```
(base) ip-75-193:Home trevormartin$ mkdir Test
(base) ip-75-193:Home trevormartin$ cd Test
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ emacs processResults.py
         (copy my code for processResults.py)
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ emacs generate_results.py
         (copy my code for generate_results.py)
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ mkdir N_Test
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ mkdir UN_Test
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd N_Test
(base) ip-75-193:N_Test trevormartin$ mkdir x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5
(base) ip-75-193:N_Test trevormartin$ cd ..
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd UN_Test
(base) ip-75-193:UN_Test trevormartin$ mkdir xx_1 xx_2 xx_3 xx_4 xx_5
(base) ip-75-193:UN_Test trevormartin$ cd ..
```

You are now good to go.

Now I will give you the idea of what used to be done manually.

```
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cp processResults.py ./N_Test/x_1
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cp processResults.py ./N_Test/x_2
.
.
.
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cp processResults.py ./N_Test/x_5


(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cp processResults.py ./UN_Test/xx_1
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cp processResults.py ./UN_Test/xx_2
.
.
.
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cp processResults.py ./UN_Test/xx_5


(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd ./N_Test/x_1; python3 processResults.py; cd ..; cd ..
.
.
.
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd ./N_Test/x_5; python3 processResults.py; cd ..; cd ..


(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd ./UN_Test/xx_1; python3 processResults.py; cd ..; cd ..
.
.
.
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd ./UN_Test/xx_5; python3 processResults.py; cd ..; cd ..


(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd ./N_Test
(base) ip-75-193:N_Test trevormartin$ ls 
x_1         x_2         x_4
x_3         x_5
(base) ip-75-193:N_Test trevormartin$ cd x_1; ls
processResults.py   results
(base) ip-75-193:x_1 trevormartin$ cd results; ls
Summary_Total.csv
(base) ip-75-193:results trevormartin$ cat Summary_Total.csv
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

I would then copy each Summary_Total.csv across all subdirectories into a large csv file for each data folder.

Here is the demonstration of the automated one. There are no files in the subdirectories x_1,...,x_5 and xx_1,...,xx_5 at this point.

```
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ ls
N_Test          UN_Test         processResults.py     generate_results.py
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cd N_Test; ls; cd ..
x_1         x_3         x_5
x_2         x_4
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ python3 generate_results.py
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ ls 
N_Test          UN_Test       processResults.py
N_Test.csv      UN_Test.csv   generate_results.py
(base) ip-75-193:Test trevormartin$ cat N_Test.csv
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Here is **generate_results.py** that I would like to improve and here is **processResults.py**, which is called by **generate_results.py**

**generate_results.py**

```
'''                                                                                                                      
Automates running processResults.py and then concatentating the                                                          
csv files into a large csv file                                                                                          
'''
import csv
import pandas
import os
from subprocess import Popen, call
from functools import reduce


cwd = os.getcwd()
dirs = os.listdir(path='.')

# all data dirs begin with N or U, no other dirs begin with these letters                                                
needed_dirs = [cwd+'/'+dir for dir in dirs if dir[0] == 'N' or dir[0] == 'U']


for dir in needed_dirs:
    # this only matters if num data folders > 1                                                                          
    os.chdir(cwd)

    # copy processResults.py into data folder (i.e. N_Test or UN_Test)                                                   
    process1 = Popen(['cp','processResults.py',dir])
    process1.communicate()

    # change directory to inside data folder (i.e. ./N_Test or ./UN_Test)                                                
    os.chdir(dir)
    cwd2 = os.getcwd()
    # get all sub dirs in this directory                                                                                 
    sub_dirs = next(os.walk('.'))[1]

    # needed_subs will look like ['cwd/N_Test/x_1'...'cwd/N_Test/x_5']                                                   
    needed_subs = [cwd2+'/'+sub_dir for sub_dir in sub_dirs]

    summaries_csvs = []

    for sub_dir in needed_subs:
        # put processResults.py into each sub_directory                                                                  
        call(["cp","processResults.py",sub_dir])
        os.chdir(sub_dir)
        # run processResults.py                                                                                          
        call(["python3","processResults.py"])

    # change the directory back                                                                                          
    os.chdir(dir)

    for sub_dir in needed_subs:
        # go into each 'results' (generated by processResults.py) and collect all summary csvs                           
        os.chdir(sub_dir+'/results')
        summary = pandas.read_csv('Summary_Total.csv', delimiter=',')
        summaries_csvs.append(summary)

    # concatenate all csvs as a pandas dataframe                                                                         
    all_dfs = pandas.concat(summaries_csvs).reset_index(drop=True)

    # convert the summaries for a given data folder into a large csv (i.e N_Test.csv or UN_Test.csv)                     
    all_dfs.to_csv(path_or_buf=dir+'.csv',
                   columns=all_dfs.columns,
                   index=False,
                   sep=',',
                   encoding='utf-8')
```

**processResults.py**

```
'''                                                                                                                      
Artificial process.py that illustrates proof of concept.                                                                 

This artificial process.py creates a subdirectory called 'results'                                                       
in the current directory and generates a Summary_Total.csv file                                                          
that contains data.                                                                                                      
'''
import csv
import os


data = [['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [3,3,3,3,3,3,3]]

if not os.path.exists('results'):
    os.mkdir('results')

with open('results/'+'Summary_Total.csv', "w") as file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in data:
        file_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: 1) With "*if I have two data files, then each of these will have 5 subdirectories*", I guess you meant "two data **folders**" (`N_Test`, `UN_Test`). 2) `processResults.py` script has `data` as a common hardcoded list - but where does the real csv data for each sub-folder come from, how they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying `processResults.py` into the subdirectories is unnecessary and clutters up the code and your disk drive.  Change `processResults.py` so that it takes a path of the directory to process.  Better still, turn processResults.py into a function and combine the two scripts into one much simpler one.  Without the overhead of using `POpen()` or `call()` this should run faster.

```
'''                                                                                                                      
Automates data processing and collection
'''

import csv
from pathlib import Path


def process(directory='.'):
    '''
    Artificial process() function that generates and returns
    dummy Summary_Total data.
    '''

    header = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
    directory = Path(directory).resolve()
    name = directory.parts[-1]
    data = [[name] + [i]*(len(header) - 1) for i in range(1, 4)]

    return [header] + data


def write_csv(path, rows):
    '''
    Boilerplate for writing a list of lists to a csv file
    '''

    with path.open('w', newline='') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerows(rows)


def generate_results(pattern='*'):
    '''
    Automates processing each data directory under folders matching the glob-style pattern
    and creating individual and collective summary CSV's
    '''
    for folder in Path('.').glob(pattern):

        summaries_csvs = []

        # if the sub_dirs need to be done in order, use sorted(folder.iterdir())
        for sub_dir in folder.iterdir():
            if sub_dir.is_dir():
                sub_dir = sub_dir.resolve()

                summary = process(sub_dir)

                # for the big csv, only include the header from the first summary data
                if not summaries_csvs:
                    summaries_csvs.extend(summary)
                else:
                    summaries_csvs.extend(summary[1:])

                result_dir = sub_dir / 'results'
                result_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

                # this is the individual csv in each data sub_dir
                write_csv(result_dir / 'Summary_Total.csv', summary)

        # this is the collective summary csv in each data folder
        write_csv(folder.with_suffix('.csv'), summaries_csvs)


# process data folders that match the glob pattern
generate_results('Test/[UN]*Test')
```